# Downloading a string from a website?

Tags: c#, php, webclient

I've been looking how to download a string from a PHP script which is hosted by Infinity Free. The examples I have been seeing online uses WebClient to download the string with:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
string reply = client.DownloadString ("<address>");
Console.WriteLine (reply);
```

But it just gives me an error saying "please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support". Whats more confusing for me is that there is no javascript on the web page. So why is javascript needed?

My PHP file just uses echo to display the string.

Comment: Sounds like Infinity Free is 'wrapping' your website with some nonsense, which checks for javascript, and probably cookies, and adblockers, and all manner of bs.

Comment: Yeah it’ll be something like that because I’ve jusf hosted it in 000webhost and it’s working fine now.

Thanks

Comment: I hate that auto-wrapped crap. I like to be in 100% control of the content from a web directory :) Glad you got that sorted, and can continue on now knowing it was them messing up your code!